# GTK error in VMware Player for 12.04 LTS

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

Installing VMware Player for 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

https://www.vmware.com/go/downloadplayer

I get these errors:

```
$ sudo sh VMware-Player-6.0.0-1295980.x86_64.bundle
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
(vmware-installer.py:8805): Gtk-WARNING **:
Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module":
libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory
```

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gtk2-engines
sudo apt-get install gtk-murrine-engine
sudo apt-get install gtk2-murrine-engine
sudo apt-get install gtk2-murrine-engine:i386
```

Has anyone fixed this?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. "Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: I am having the same problem as well, i tried linking /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so -> /usr/lib/libcanberra-gtk-module.so, and that got rid of canberra error, but still cant find murrine

Comment: sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-* This solved the problem for me:)

Answer (score 3):

The libcanberra errors seems to be resolvable using a symbolic link as follows:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so /usr/lib/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
```

Also, you'll need the `build-essential`, `open-vm-tools` and `open-vm-toolbox` packages, install them using:

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential open-vm-tools open-vm-toolbox
```

---

[(Source)](https://superuser.com/questions/683402/installing-vmware-player-on-kali-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Install libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a solved my problem. I am running 12.04.4.